# How to store ID from a drawable in SQlite database and retrieve it again?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to store the ID of a drawable (like R.drawable.image) in my SQlite database and retrieve that ID later to put in a listView. I don't want to save the image as a BLOB i only want to store the ID.

Right now I create a table like this where i store the ID of a drawable:

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE cards \n" +
            "(\n" +
            "card_id INT PRIMARY KEY, \n" +
            "cpr VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,\n" +
            "card_type VARCHAR(30), \n" +
            "front_photo VARCHAR(30), back_photo BLOB,\n" +
            "FOREIGN KEY (cpr) REFERENCES users(cpr)\n" +
            ")\n" +
            ";\n");

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO cards (card_id , cpr, card_type, front_photo) VALUES(1, '170492-1802','Rejsekort', 'R.drawable.rejsekort_f');"
    );
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO cards (card_id , cpr, card_type, front_photo) VALUES(2, '170492-1802','Bank Card', 'R.drawable.bankcard_f');"
    );
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO cards (card_id , cpr, card_type, front_photo) VALUES(3, '170492-1802','Drivers Licence', 'R.drawable.bankcard_f');"
    );
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO cards (card_id , cpr, card_type, front_photo) VALUES(4, '170492-1802','Sundhedskort', 'R.drawable.bankcard_f');"
    );
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO cards (card_id , cpr, card_type, front_photo) VALUES(5, '170492-1802','Ungdomskort', 'R.drawable.bankcard_f');"
    );
```

Then I try to get all the ID's of that table and add them to an Integer ArrayList so I can display them in a ListView like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> images=new ArrayList<Integer>();
public void addImagesToListview() {
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor getImages = db.rawQuery("Select front_photo from cards", null);
    getImages.moveToFirst();
    while(!getImages.isAfterLast()) {
        String image = getImages.getString(0);
        int image2 = Integer.parseInt(image);
        images.add(image2);
        getImages.moveToNext(); }
```

But for some reason the app crashes? I'm able to add ID's of drawables in my ArrayList like this:

`images.add(R.drawable.image);`

So why doesn't it work when i just store that ID in the database and retrieve it again so it looks something like this:

`images.add("ID from database");`

Comment: `... for some reason the app crashes ...` For some reasons you didn't post your logcat.

Comment: Your field type is a String, you need an int, `front_photo VARCHAR(30)`, also, you are inserting the raw String 'R.drawable.bankcard_f' into the database, instead of evaluating it, and inserting the ID. You app is crashing because `R.drawable.bankcard_f` != Integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you database to

```
front_photo INT
```

and when you insert your rows, insert the evaluated ID, not the string that represents it.

```
int photoID = R.drawable.rejsekort_f;
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO cards (card_id , cpr, card_type, front_photo) VALUES(1, '170492-1802','Rejsekort', " + photoID + ");";
```